# Spring Boot CORS - Execute code on forbidden origin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cors

I have CORS set up in a SecurityFilterChain to accept a list of origins, like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityChain {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                (authorizeRequests) -> authorizeRequests.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.HEAD, "/**").permitAll())
                .cors((cors) -> cors
                        .configurationSource(configureCors()));
        return http.build();
    }

    CorsConfigurationSource configureCors() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList("origin1", "origin2"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS", "HEAD"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

The request mappings are also annotated with `@CrossOrigin` with the same list of origins.

I want to be able to modify the `ServletResponse` when a request origin is rejected (by adding a unique response header). I have tried doing so in a `Filter` implementation, but if the origin is rejected the request won't reach the Filter code.

How can I modify the response when the filter chain rejects a cross-origin request?

Comment: When a provided @annotation is used, it is a little bit complicated to custom filters. Spring boot is owner of the http pipeline. It is an option to use a custom cors implementation?

Comment: "I want to be able to modify the ServletResponse when a request origin is rejected (by adding a unique response header)" - that is not possible due to design of CORS: CORS rules are evaluated on browser side and the purpose of those rules is to relax browser's default same origin policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a provided @annotation is used, it is a little bit complicated to use custom filters. Spring boot is jealous owner of the entire http pipeline.

Here a few options intercept the response and add whatever you want to the response instance

### #1 @Filter + @Order(1)

With this two annotation I was able to catch the final response and add my custom headers

```java
package org.jrichardsz.acme.filters;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Order(1)
public class ResponseHeaderFilter implements Filter {
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    res.addHeader("x-foo-response", "bar-value");
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

**Lectures:**

- [@Order annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/annotation/Order.html)
- https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-add-filter
- https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/multi/multi__global_filters.html

### #2 Custom Cors

If the #1 did not work, remove all the @Cors and create your own cors filter

```java
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain)
  throws IOException, ServletException {

  HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
  System.out.println("CORSFilter HTTP Request: " + request.getMethod());

  // Authorize (allow) all domains to consume the content
  ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, POST");

  HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

  // For HTTP OPTIONS verb/method reply with ACCEPTED status code -- per CORS handshake
  if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
    resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_ACCEPTED);
    return;
  }

  // pass the request along the filter chain
  chain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
}
```

Source: https://howtodoinjava.com/java/servlets/java-cors-filter-example/

**Lectures:**

- https://gist.github.com/nejckorasa/d68b8bafb6235ef33ad552d2e2c12fd6

Comment: Better use an established and proven CORS middleware than write your own. Unless you're intimately familiar with the CORS protocol, writing a custom CORS middleware simply is too error-prone. Case in point: `request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")` is too restrictive and miscategorises all `OPTIONS` requests as preflight requests; more on this topic on https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#4-categorise-requests-correctly

Comment: I used option 1 to get it working with Spring's built-in CORS. The only change I needed was annotating the filter with `@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE + 1)`.

Comment: If it helped you, don't forget to mark as solved and or useful ;)